# Deleting Specific Data From Database Row (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I'm trying to allow (a user), to delete data from the database and replace it with updated information.

The problem I run into is this:

> SqlException was unhandled: Incorrect syntax near ','.

And this error appears at the first: `sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Here is the full code for the "Apply Edits" button:

```
private void applybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Connection();
        sqlconnection.Open();

        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE Item, Quantity, description, datasheet FROM inventory_table WHERE id= " + ID, sqlconnection);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE inventory_table SET Item = @Item, Quantity = @Quantity, description = @description, datasheet = @datasheet "+
            "WHERE id= " + ID, sqlconnection);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", this.txtbx1.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", this.txtbx2.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", this.txtbx3.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datasheet", this.txtbx4.Text);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlconnection.Close();    
    }
```

Comment: You cannot delete just a few columns from a SQL Server table - you can only delete **complete rows**. If you want to "delete" some columns - you need to use an `UPDATE (table) SET column1 = NULL` or something similar

Comment: The syntax error is caused by the incorrect syntax for the delete command but you don't need to delete the row because the old values are replaced by the new ones passed to the update command

Comment: You would just need an update to change the old values to the current values.  Why do you need to delete?

Comment: As a side note you might want to take a look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: I've taken out the "DELETE" command, and it works. Thank you for all the replies!

Comment: Another thing, never concat strings and then execute it. Always parameterize.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void applybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Connection();
        sqlconnection.Open();

        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM inventory_table WHERE id= " + ID, sqlconnection);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE inventory_table SET Item = @Item, Quantity = @Quantity, description = @description, datasheet = @datasheet "+
            "WHERE id= " + ID, sqlconnection);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", this.txtbx1.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", this.txtbx2.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", this.txtbx3.Text);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datasheet", this.txtbx4.Text);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlconnection.Close();    
    }
```

Comment: Rather than concatenating the idea on the end please remember to always use a parameter otherwise you are leaving yourself wide open to sql injection attacks